# Java file to upperCase and lowerUpper

Tags: java, file-io, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to change all file names in directory to different case combined lower and upper example: TextFile == tExTfIlE and after I change the name I want ot open the file and make all text in it in the same as shown above case but I have no clue how. I have the code for changing case to what I want but it doubles the thing for example: TextFile == TetExtXtFifIlELe... how can I do this things here's the code I've done so far

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileOps {
    public static File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files");
    public static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void toUpperCase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                String name = null;
                int value = 1;
                // this for should loop trough current file name and change letters 
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles[i].getName().length(); j++) {
                    if (value == 1) {
                        name += Character.toLowerCase(listOfFiles[i].getName().charAt(j));
                        value = 2;
                    }
                    if (value == 2) {
                        name += Character.toUpperCase(listOfFiles[i].getName().charAt(j));
                        value = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (listOfFiles[i].renameTo(new File(folder, name))) {
                    // Here it should go into the file and make the content to the same type case as the name, But how can I open the file and do the same thing with the content as I do in the name?
                    System.out.println("Done");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nope");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put yourself in the position of the computer and work through the loop.  Pay special attention to the `if (value == ...)` checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start by creating a helper method to mix the case one `String` at a time, something like -

```
public static String mixCase(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (in != null) {
        char[] arr = in.toCharArray();
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            char f = arr[0];
            boolean first = Character.isUpperCase(f);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sb.append((first) ? Character.toLowerCase(arr[i])
                        : Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]));
                first = !first;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I tested it with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mixCase("TextFile"));
    System.out.println(mixCase("reverse"));
}
```

Output is

```
tExTfIlE
ReVeRsE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

```
String name = null;
```

Don't start with a `null` `String`, otherwise, you will have a file name starting with "null" when you first concatenate something to it. Start with an empty `String`:

```
String name = "";
```

---

But, your main problem is here:

```
if (value == 1) {
    // ...
    value = 2;
}
if (value == 2) {
    // ...
    value = 1;
}
```

You will always enter the two `if` when value is `1`, because at the end of the first `if` block, you are changing the value to `2`, and testing if the value is `2` at the beginning of the second block. If you want to do that, you have to add an `else`:

```
if (value == 1) {
    // ...
    value = 2;
} else if (value == 2) {
    // ...
    value = 1;
}
```

Comment: Would it work if after the first change of value i add countinue; ?